# JS Script to go back to previous page using webdriver doesnt work

Tags: javascript, selenium

My code spinet is as follow:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.history.go(-1);");
```

The above code doest work please suggest.
I tried above code by casting webdriver instant but did not work every time
I don’t want to use `driver.navigate().back()` command as it not recommended.
Please suggest...

Comment: May I know why driver.navigate().back() command is not recommended?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are not using `driver.navigate().back()`. It's the recommended one. Anyways, below is the way to do in javascript:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("window.history.back();");
```

**Note:** Might require a sleep time of 2-3 seconds. But, it works, nonetheless.